# execute a string in a bash script containing multiple redirects

Tags: bash, scripting, pipe, io-redirection

I am trying to write a bash script which simply acts as an emulator. It takes input from the user and executes the command while forwarding the command along with the result onto a file. I am unable to handle inputs which have either a | or a > in them.

The only option I could find was segregating the commands based on the | into an array and run them individually. However, this does not allow > redirects.

Thanking in advance.

$cmd is a command taken as input from the user

I used the command
$cmd 2>&1 | tee -a $flname

but this does not work if there is a | or a > in $cmd

/bin/bash -c "$cmd 2>&1 | tee -a $flname" does not run/store the command either

Comment: Show us the script you have so far

Comment: `SCRIPT='echo this | cat'; eval "$SCRIPT"`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  Most of us here are happy to help you improve your craft, but are less happy acting as short-order unpaid programming staff. Show us your work so far as a [mcve], the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out. It may help to re-read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -r -p "Insert command to execute"$'\n' cmd
echo "Executing '$cmd'"
/bin/bash -c "$cmd"
# or eval "$cmd"
```

Example of execution:

```
$ ./script.sh 
Insert command to execute
printf '1\n2\n3\n4\n' | grep '1\|3'
Executing 'printf '1\n2\n3\n4\n' | grep '1\|3''
1
3
```

Comment: Thanks Kamil. This works perfect if there is no redirect of the sort 2>&1 | tee -a flname. I noticed I had missed this in my initial question